# heavy memory usage when using very large images

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, uiimageview, ios8.1

We are using 3 `UIImageView` in our interface ,2 for important tasks and 1 just for `VisualEffectView`.

We are getting heavy memory usage and at times "Received Memory Warnings" in debug area even after using JPG compression.(only when using very large images taken from dslr cameras)

And even "connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died" warnings.

where are we doing wrong here?

Here is our didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo  code below.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *selectedImage=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *selectedImgDataforCompression= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.1) ;
    UIImage *compressedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:selectedImgDataforCompression];


    VisualEffectImageVIew.image=compressedImage;
    BackgroundImageView.image=compressedImage;
    ForegroundImageView.image=compressedImage;
   if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {


        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

        [self popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:popoverController];
  }

}
```

Memory report below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TnJC.png

Answer (score 0):

JPEG compression does nothing at all to help you here. It only reduces file size when writing to disk. A `UIImage` will take an amount of memory proportional to the number of pixels in the image.

You need to scale the images appropriately to fit the screen. An image from a modern DSLR is far too big to be used natively as a background image - an iPhone 5S is 640 pixels wide, a 12 megapixel image will be about 4000 pixels wide.

There is a nice writeup of image scaling techniques [here](http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/).

Comment: coming to DSLR image ,I have image taken from DSLR camera but it's resolution is around 4000x4000 as far as I have seen photo editors can handle this resolution images, but about my code ,is there anything to be done or any correction to be done?

Comment: What are you using the images for? If they are just for display, you have to make a smaller image before putting it in a UIImageView, otherwise you will be using too much memory and the image view will be constantly working to scale the image.

Comment: we'll be using those images for editing,filtering etc

Comment: You still need to separate out displaying the image from processing it. Unless the user is looking at 1:1 pixel representations then you must scale what you see on the screen. If they're looking at the full image then you probably need to look at a CATiledLayer or something, but I don't have any experience with that in this context.

Comment: Thanks and Sure we'll look into that